# Getting the nearest results in Geocoder and show them and some other questions about Geocoder

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I am working on an application which will have a textview/searchview or a more preferrable way to take a String, make a search of that string and show some results. And whenever the user clicks one of the result it will take user to the another Intent which have a map that points to the clicked results.

I am searching this for days, I read many articles in here, or in Google Developer pages, I know that I need to use Geocoder, and for this I think the best one for my app is this Google API

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+geocodingSearch+"&components=country:TR&sensor=false";
```

geocodingSearch will be the String that written by user.

*My first question is does `sensor=true` makes a big difference? Do you prefer to use it? Or do you prefer something else?

*In Google's example it uses `region=es` in one of them and `components=country:ES` in another of them. What are the differences between them? Also does it works perfectly, or using borders is better?

*I don't have any problem of parsing JSON answer, but I am not sure about how to show the results. I want it to be seen as the way that search results as in the bottom. It doesn't need to make a search as the user types, but the result part will be better like this. Do I need to use a `SearchView` or something else?

*And the final question is written in the title. Is it possible to get the nearest results at top in Google API part (I am able to get the Location), I don't want to limit by borders, but getting the nearest results will be better. If this is not possible I will try to sort them by making calculations with LatLong values.

Thanks in advance, and I will be greatful by your helps.

[image]